# "Schwer" oder "schwierig"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, adjective

Ich habe beide Varianten gelesen:

> Ungarisch ist schwer

und (vielleicht öfter)

> Ungarisch ist schwierig.

Gibt es da einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung? Wenn nicht, ist die Form *schwierig* tatsächlich üblicher?

**Edit: Ergänzung** .
 Es ist jetzt klar, dass beide Adjektive benutzt werden können. Es bleiben die Fragen:

- Empfindet Ihr einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung der oben genannten Sätze?
- Einen stilistischen Unterschied (z. B. mehr oder weniger umgangssprachlich)?
- Werden sie mit gleicher Frequenz verwendet?

Comment: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,307495,00.html

Comment: Man sagt: "Deutsche Sprache, schwere Sprache." aber nicht "Deutsche Sprache, schwierige Sprache".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zwischen den Sätzen "Ungarisch ist schwer" und "Ungarisch ist schwierig" gibt es keinen Bedeutungsunterschied.

Ob es einen stilistischen Unterschied gibt, halte ich für subjektiv; meinem Empfinden nach ist auch der vernachlässigbar. "Schwierig" klingt in diesem Kontext für mich **marginal** "höherwertig", was vielleicht daran liegt, dass es a) länger ist als "schwer" und b) anders als "schwer" nicht ambig ist.

Um Unterschiede in der Frequenz zu ermitteln, müsste man mal eine Korpusanalyse machen; mir fällt von keinem der beiden auf, dass es deutlich häufiger sei als das andere.

Comment: Ich stimme zu, dass "schwierig" etwas schöner und präziser ist. Ich denke, "schwer" ist *umgangssprachlich* häufiger, wahrscheinlich einfach weil es kürzer ist.

Answer (score 10):

**Schwer** bedeutet sowohl *heavy* als auch *difficult*.

**Schwierig** bedeutet nur *difficult*.

Für *difficult* kannst Du beide gleichermaßen verwenden.

---

Das Gleiche gilt für **einfach** (*easy*, also *simple*) und **leicht** (*easy*, *light*)

---

> Gibt es da einen Unterschied in Meinung?

Achtung: false friend! **Meinung** heißt *opinion*, *meaning* heißt auf Deutsch **Bedeutung**. Korrekt heißt die Frage "Gibt es einen Unterschied **in der Bedeutung**?".

Comment: Du hast völlig Recht, elena, vielen Dank. Und das Schlimmste ist, dass ich den Unterschied zwischen "Meinung" und "Bedeutung sehr gut kenne! Ich habe den Fehler jetzt korrigiert.

Comment: Aber die (korrigierte) Frage bleibt: gibt es einen  Unterschied in der Bedeutung? In der Frequenz? Im Stil?

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist schwer eher umgangssprachlich, während schwierig eher formal ist.

Answer (score 6):

*Schwierig* würde ich bevorzugen - es geht ja schließlich um eine *Schwierigkeit*, mit dem Ungarischen, nicht um eine *Schwerigkeit* (Hinweis: *Schwerigkeit* gibt es nicht als sinnvolles Wort)

Solange sich *schwer* aber auf etwas Abstraktes (hier implizit: ungarische Sprache bzw. diese zu lernen/sprechen) bezieht, dann wird es normalerweise schon als Synonym zu *schwierig* verstanden.

Verwechslungsgefahr besteht nur, wenn *schwer* sich auf ein Wort bezieht, das einen physikalischen Gegenstand beschreibt, da es dann auch das physikalische Gewicht beschreiben könnte statt nur eine abstrakte Schwierigkeit.

Mir fällt jetzt aber kein Beispiel ein, wo diese Gefahr wirklich auftreten könnte - man müsste einen Satz nachlässig und stark verkürzt formulieren, um eine Verwechslungsgefahr herzustellen.

---

Ein Beispiel für eine Verwechslungsgefahr wäre:

> Dieses Ungarisch-Buch ist sehr schwer

Wiegt es 10 kg oder ist es schwer zu verstehen? In diesem Fall kann man die Zweideutigkeit auflösen, indem man sagt

> Dieses Ungarisch-Buch ist sehr schwer *zu lesen*

oder

> Dieses Ungarisch-Buch ist sehr *schwierig*

Comment: Klar gibt es das Wort *Schwierigkeit*: difficulty.

Comment: @elena: Ja, aber *Schwerigkeit* gibt es nicht, das meinte Hackworth. Aber vielleicht könnte man *Schwere* sagen ;)

Comment: In meiner Frage hatte ich überhaupt nicht an eine Verwechslungsgefahr gedacht: ich wollte nur wissen was bei Deutschsprachigen besser klingt. Aber, nur zum Spaß, hier ist ein zweideutiger Satz: *Mein  Lehrbuch "Ungarisch in drei Wochen" ist sehr schwer*.

Comment: Noch nie drüber nachgedacht: Wenn es *Schwerigkeit* nicht gibt, was ist dann das Gegenteil von "Schwerelosigkeit"? ;)

Comment: @musiKk: Anziehungskraft. Bzw. Schwere, wie OregonGhost bereits erklärte.

Answer (score 1):

Unter den Bedeutungen von "schwer" findet sich auch: "schwierig, nicht leicht zu bewältigen" (siehe [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwer)).

Diese Art der Verwendung kommt aus der Umgangssprache und wird von manchen Leuten als nicht ganz korrekt empfunden. Siehe dazu [diese](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article2788684.html) Diskussion. Auch ich würde in deinem Beispiel auf jeden Fall "schwierig" verwenden, also:

> Ungarisch ist schwierig.

Answer (score 1):

In der Umgangssprache wird schwierig meistens durch das kürzere "schwer" ersetzt.
In gepflegter geschriebener Sprache unterscheidet man schon noch zwischen schwer (Gewicht) und schwierig (nicht einfach).

Answer (score -1):

**Schwer** ist tendenziell eher als Adjektiv in Gebrauch, **schwierig** eher als Adverb.

Comment: Beide Wörter sind **Adjektive**; *schwer* kann man aber auch als Adverb einsetzen (*"er hat schwer gelitten"*).